# java wso2esb developer studio

Tags: java, wso2

I have installed Eclipse Luna( wso2developer studio) but when i open eclipse i am facing this error An error has occurred See the log file null.

Log file:

```
!SESSION 2015-10-13 01:50:23.162 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.7.0_17
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository file:/home/developerstudio/wso2/developer-studio/features/installed-distributions/developer-studio-eclipse-jee-luna-win64-x86_64/target/p2-repo -destination /home/developerstudio/wso2/developer-studio/features/installed-distributions/developer-studio-eclipse-jee-luna-win64-x86_64/target/eclipse -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.appserver.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.appserver.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.bpel.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.bpel.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.registry.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.registry.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.esb.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.esb.graphical.editor.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.ds.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.ds.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.usermgt.core.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbon.uibundle.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.capp.framework.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.registry.connector.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.server.framework.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.framework.core.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.framework.samples.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbonserver.30.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbonserver.31.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbonserver.32.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbonserver.40.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbonserver.42.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbonserver.44.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbonserver.remote.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.security.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.jboss.tools.smooks.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.distribution.project.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.artifact.library.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gadget.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gs.jaggery.feature.feature.group -installIU org.smooks.edi.editor-feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.brs.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.appfactory.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.apim.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.jaggery.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.analytics.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.soapui.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.tcpmon.feature.feature.group
Command-line arguments:  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository file:/home/developerstudio/wso2/developer-studio/features/installed-distributions/developer-studio-eclipse-jee-luna-win64-x86_64/target/p2-repo -destination /home/developerstudio/wso2/developer-studio/features/installed-distributions/developer-studio-eclipse-jee-luna-win64-x86_64/target/eclipse -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.appserver.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.appserver.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.bpel.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.bpel.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.registry.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.registry.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.esb.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.esb.graphical.editor.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.ds.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.ds.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.usermgt.core.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbon.uibundle.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.capp.framework.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.registry.connector.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.server.framework.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.framework.core.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.framework.samples.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbonserver.30.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbonserver.31.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbonserver.32.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbonserver.40.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbonserver.42.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbonserver.44.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.carbonserver.remote.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.security.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.jboss.tools.smooks.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.distribution.project.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.artifact.library.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gadget.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gs.jaggery.feature.feature.group -installIU org.smooks.edi.editor-feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.brs.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.appfactory.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.apim.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.jaggery.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.analytics.artifact.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.soapui.feature.feature.group -installIU org.wso2.tcpmon.feature.feature.group

!ENTRY org.eclipse.compare.win32 4 0 2015-10-13 01:50:32.379
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.compare.win32 [68]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: eclipse.platform; filter:="(osgi.os=win32)"
```

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded the right package for your system? It looks like you are running linux x86_64 and the log shows Win32 platform. I downloaded and started the package successfully just a few minutes ago from [this](http://product-dist.wso2.com/products/developer-studio/3.8.0/developer-studio-eclipse-jee-luna-linux-gtk-x86_64-3.8.0.zip) link.

Comment: now i am downloading again the file i have windows 64 bit , i am using wso2 esb for my office work we are using xml code is there any option so we can make API's in java code like FUSE ESB i have also worked on FUSE ESB with JBOSS FUSE Server. i need little help

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue about wso2esb but I see that there is a difference between the OS that the bootloader reported and the platform filter that is applied in the last line. You should download the distribution that matches your OS, for sure. :)